# How to estimate a limit value of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=(x-y)(1-x^2-y^2)\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=(x+y)(1-x^2-y^2)$$
Initial condition $x(0),y(0)$ are nonzero real numbers.

How to estimate the solution $x(t)$ as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Note that you could combine the answers below to find the exact limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} (x(t),y(t))$ for any initial condition.

Answer (score 2):

If $z=x+iy$ then
$$\dot z = (1+i)z(1-|z|^2)$$
so that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\arg z = Im(\frac{\dot z}{z})=1-|z|^2=Re(\frac{\dot z}{z})=\frac{d}{dt}\ln|z|
$$
which integrates to
$$\arg(z(t))-\arg(z(0))=\ln|z(t)|-\ln|z(0)|.$$
If, as per the other answers, $|z(t)|\to 1$ for $t\to\infty$ then 
$$\arg(z(\infty))=\arg(z(0))-\ln|z(0)|,$$
all angles up to multiples of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

The common factor $(1-x^2-y^2)$ is just a rescaling of the vector field (with different signs inside and outside the unit circle). So the orbits agree, up to time parametrization and possibly a change of direction, with those of the linear system $dx/dt=x-y$, $dy/dt=x+y$. (And the behaviour *on* the unit circle is of course different too.) So if you can solve the linear system, then you should be able to figure out the answer.

Compare the phase portraits (on Wolfram Alpha): [linear](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7Bx-y,x%2By%7D), [rescaled](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7B(x-y)(1-x%5E2-y%5E2),(x%2By)(1-x%5E2-y%5E2)%7D,%7Bx,-2,2%7D,%7By,-2,2%7D).

Comment: This is a very nice answer but (I think) could do with a little elaboration because the time parameterisation is integrable. Your answer could be used to find the exact limiting solution for any initial condition

Comment: @copper.hat: Sure, but since there wasn't any effort at all shown in the question to begin with, I didn't want to give the whole solution.

Comment: I agree with you. However, something in my childish nature just wants to finish the solution :-).

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $(x(0),y(0))= (0,0)$ or $x^2(0)+y^2(0) = 1$, then
$(x(t),y(t))=(x(0),y(0))$ for all $t$.

Let $s(t) = x^2(t)+y^2(t)$, then
$\dot{s} = f(s)=2(1-s)s$.

Note that $f(0)=f(1) = 0$, if $s \in [0,1]$ then $f(s) \ge0$ and
if $s \ge 1$ then $f(s)  \le 0$.

In particular, if $s(0) >0$ then $\lim_{t \to \infty} s(t) = 1$. In fact, since this is a one dimensional ODE, we know that if $s(0) \in (0,1]$ then $\lim_{t \uparrow \infty} s(t) = 1$ and if
$s(0) \ge 1$ then $\lim_{t \downarrow \infty} s(t) = 1$.

We can find an explicit estimate for the convergence of $s(t)$. Note that for $s\ge 1$ we have $f(s) \le 2(1-s)$ and so $\dot{(s-1}) \le -2 (s-1)$ which gives $0 \le s(t)-1 \le (s(t_0)-1) e^{-2(t-t_0)}$ for $s(t_0) \ge 1$.

Note that for any $\alpha <2$ we can find some $\delta>0$ such that if $s \in [1-\delta,1]$ then $f(s) \ge \alpha (1-s)$. Hence if $s(t_0) \in [1-\delta,1]$, we have $0 \le 1-s(t) \le (1-s(t_0)) e^{-\alpha(t-t_0)}$.

Hence for sufficiently large $t_0$ we have the estimate
$|1-s(t)| \le |1-s(t_0)| e^{-\alpha(t-t_0)}$.

If we let $w=(x,y)$ then we can write the ODE as
$\dot{w} = (1-\|w\|^2) Aw$ for some matrix $A$ and we are given $w(0) \neq 0$. Let $s(t)= \|w(t)\|^2$, then we note that $s(t) \to 1$ hence
the solution is bounded, and so there is some $K$ such that
$\|\dot{w}\| \le K \|A\| |1-s(t)|$, in particular $t \mapsto \|\dot{w}(t)\|$ is integrable and hence $w$ converges.

Comment: Thank you. I think this logic is good. But I don't find the limit of x(t)

Comment: You have an estimate, which is what the question asked...

Comment: You could use Hans answer to find an exact limit, as I have already mentioned.